# Mod Rewrite and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect pages using mod_rewrite to the pages with some variables (for using them with PHP's `$_GET`).

To give an example with few lines:

- When the user enters `/c/stg` it redirects to `item_show.php?id=$1&f=1` (where `f` is page number).
- When the user enters `/c/stg/2` it redirects to the second page with `show.php?id=$1&f=$2`.

I think there are no errors or misuses of these in my file but, here's what I want:

I want user to enter `/`*`string`* directly to go `item_show.php?id=$1&f=1` with `$1` is our *string* of course...

But when I change my file by removing the `/c/` part from `RewriteRule` it starts giving errors in all other directories and doesn't read any files (`my.css`) even though I have already defined a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`...

Do you have any suggestions?
Or how can I made this system possible with any method?

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#user
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]

#marked
RewriteRule ^marked/([^/]+)/?$ item_marked.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

#content
RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/?$ item_show.php?id=$1&f=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ item_show.php?id=$1&f=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: First suggestion: post the contents of the file with these rules in it. And is it the main server configuration, or a .htaccess file?

Comment: Current .htaccess file is here:

Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#user
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]

#marked
RewriteRule ^marked/([^/]+)/?$ item_marked.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

#content
RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/?$ item_show.php?id=$1&f=1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ item_show.php?id=$1&f=$2 [L,NC]

Comment: Removing the c/ means all URLs will match your pattern … this is what you meant, right:

> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$

Comment: Yes, Nerdling i meant that, and as you said all URL's match it so it doesn't work.. But I really need a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I wrong if RewriteCond only are passed on to the first RewriteRule??

Try this instead:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#user
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#marked
RewriteRule ^marked/([^/]+)/?$ item_marked.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#content
RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/?$ item_show.php?id=$1&f=1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ item_show.php?id=$1&f=$2 [L,NC]
```

Cheers,

Comment: I'm just happy that I got a point so I can vote. :p A lot of the questions here are quite out of my knowledge. :(

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteCond` directives do only belong to the first following `RewriteRule` directive. So in your case the two `RewriteCond` direcitves are only applied to the first `RewriteRule` directive and not to the others.

But you could use this abortion rule to quit the rewrite process if the request can be mapped to an existing file or directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This would cause that following rules are only tested if the request cannot be mapped directly to an existing file or directory.